# Update Multiple Rows of Database using Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I want to update multiple data in database using interface form update. Form below shows the data displayed from database and will be update after enter the save button.

Below are my interface

[image: Interface]

Below are my Code

html:

```
<form action="{{ route('people.update', $id) }}" method="post">
@csrf
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
@foreach($peoples as $people)
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="name" name="name" value=""/>&nbsp;&nbsp; {{$people->name}}
   </td>
   <td>
    <input type="number" class="age" value="{{$people->age}}" name="age" disabled />
   </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
<button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" style="background-color: green;">Save</button>
</form>
```

Javascript/ Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.name').on('change', function () {
            let input = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.age')
            input.prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
            input.val('');
        });
      });
</script>
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $people = People::find($id);
        $people->age=$request->input('age');
        $people->save();
        return redirect('people');
    }
```

**Question:**

I cant updated the form to database, problem maybe related to controller.

How to set the controller for this scenario.

Thank You

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Trying adding ```dd($request->all())``` to the beginning of your controller code to see if ```age``` is being properly passed in (you could do the same for the ```id``` to make sure it's correct).

Answer (score 0):

your $id is for a specific person, but what you want to update are all the people selected, try to pass all selected ids to the controller using jquery.

Comment: How to do that ?
Can u show me ? Sorry I'm a newbie

Comment: or, pass the $people->id as the value of the checkbox, easier

Comment: Thank you for the idea but the pass the $people->id as the value of the checkbox also produced the same error.. I think the entire code from controller is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, use this in the blade:

```
    @foreach($people as $person)
       <tr>
          <td>
             <input type="checkbox" value="{{$person->id}}" name={{ "people[". $person->id ."][id]"}} />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" value="{{$person->name}}" name={{ "people[". $person->id ."][name]"}}  />
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="number" value="{{$person->age}}" name={{ "people[". $person->id ."][age]"}}  />
           </td>
         </tr>
         <br>
  @endforeach
```

Then verify the selected ones with this inside controller, grab the selected ids:

```
foreach(request('people') as $id => $person) {
     if(array_key_exists($person->id, $person)){ //other validations here maybe
         People::findOrFail($id)->update(['age'=>$person->age]); //not ideal for large amounts, but you get the idea here.
     }
     
}
```

Comment: The error say $id is undefined in <form action="{{ route('people.update', $id) }}" method="post">

Comment: @wanprogrammer that's because of your route definition, you used the $id as the update route parameter, if you used my way, re-define your update post route, the $id param is not passed from there any more. Good luck.